# Why doesn't StackExchange have a search feature?

Tags: discussion

Why doesn't electronics.stackexchange.com have a search q/a (site wide) feature? Or am I missing it? I see the "Tags" search, but is q/a posters didn't create a tag for the specific word/phrase you are searching site for, it seems time consuming to try to find.

Even when a use does enter tag, it only allows one word tags, not multi-word tags, which makes even search via tag cumbersome. (unless I am missing how to do multiple keyword tags too. :)

Comment: Other than the search box on the top of *every single page*?

Comment: Like.. Right on the top? BTW, the question if for Meta

Comment: If you click on a tag, it will automatically search for that tag. You can see that multi-word tags can be searched by enclosing the tag square brackets. This is a search for questions with the tags "circuit analysis" and "resistors": `[circuit-analysis] [resistors]`

Comment: The real question is why isn't the search feature prominent enough. We want new users to find the search bar without any difficulty, don't blame the user when this is a ux issue. Most sites have a magnifying glass icon in the search box. I think electronics used to have that icon but it somehow dropped off in the last redesign.

Answer (score 5):

Very Top Left of page on dark grey bar, is located a slightly lighter grey search field with even lighter grey font description. One might not notice due to lack of contrast in 3 elements, or their mind tell them feature inactive because of grey combo is standard to indicate inactive elements. But once show, it is easy to see from there on out. :)
[image]

Comment: Har har.... okay, I gotta admit. I did laugh... It's a completely pointless question and thank god someone eventually asked it. On the bright side, you did answer your own question and now you understand where the search bar is.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Comment: The method you showed in your screen shot only shows how to search for tags, if someone did not create a tag for the word you are searching for, it would not find those results. My point is Tag search is limited, and is not a site search. But no worries, someone else already answered before you and provide screen shot to answer where/how to do site wide search of all words. Then I added another screen shot after learning from them, that was even more clear where the site wide search is, because it is camouflaged. :) Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Comment: Not enough hand-drawn ellipse...

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I'm sorry, I tried! But the option was greyed out in my screenshot-software, don't know why, didn't feel like investigating at the time. I will better myself next time.

Comment: Don't I feel silly. :) Even after viewing screen shot, I did not spot it. Then I read comment ".. top of every single page", and sure enough there it was. A slightly lighter grey square on the dark grey bar, with an even lighter grey font in it stating "Search on Electrical Engineering". Just a case of worst GUI design practice tripped me up. :) Would be better if search field was much lighter grey, with black text for some contrast to differentiate and make more noticeable. A little search icon on top right with other tools would help too, or some kind of design standard to help.