# Web page format change, much wider than previously

Tags: support

Something changed at SE, or at least EE.SE in the last few hours.  I just logged in, and the same browser window size I had been using doesn't work anymore without very annoying horizontal scrolling.  It appears the reason is that the buttons HOME, QUESTIONS, TAGS, USERS, and UNANSWERED are now on the left, using up more window width.  These used to be at the top where they weren't really in the way.

On the off chance someone at SE cares, I don't like this because now I can have only one slim window on the screen at the same time, whereas previously more of *my* screen was left to my uses.  I use the browser for various things other than SE, and having to resize the window between uses is a pain.  It's also totally unnecessary for SE to require that much window width.

However, the question is, ***How can I get the old layout back?***.

Comment: You should complain on https://meta.stackexchange.com

Comment: I agree with you Olin, and I'm too lazy to complain on Meta. It's a little bit *nasty* to *force bad* GUI's down our throats.

Comment: My guess is that the updated themes are no longer optional. https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6688/electrical-engineerings-updated-site-theme-is-ready-for-testing?cb=1

Comment: @KingDuken Me no like it.

Comment: Woops... accidentally deleted my comment... My original comment: "Seems like you have to click on the left side to see questions. Kinda throws me off."

Comment: @KingDuken [I don't trust like that](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zONW46d50A0).

Comment: I can't see the breakdowns because of rep, but the question has a net 203 downvotes!

Comment: It occurs to me that our home page is useless, and should just point to the questions page instead.  Then, I wouldn't need the silly left bar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only thing you can do is to "hide left navigation" from [user's preference](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/current).

[image: "Hide left navigation"]

It will move the navigation to the top bar, beside Stack Exchange logo

[image: Expanded navigation]

Apart from that, as much as you hate it, **no, you can't get the old layout back.** (further reading: [Ch-ch-ch-changes: Left nav, responsive design, & themes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307862/ch-ch-ch-changes-left-nav-responsive-design-themes))

Comment: Thanks.  That worked in reducing the browser window width requirement.  However, now there is a extra click required to get QUESTIONS, USERS, and the like.  Not ideal, but still better than the wide window.

Comment: @OlinLathrop  Much better than wasting all that space on rarely hit links.

Comment: @Scott: Not at all, since "Questions" at least is a frequently-hit link.  I sometimes use "Users", very rarely "Tags", pretty much never "Home" or "Unanswered", but "Questions" is probably the single most common fixed link I click on.

Comment: I just noticed how annoying it is to have the questions link as a two-step process.  I agree.

Comment: I can't believe how much usability we've lost, given that these people are supposed to be experts at user interfaces.

Answer (score 3):

I've once again posted my opinions on the change, this time at https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/315639/274872.  I encourage everyone to do the same.

Comment: Instead of doing the same, I upvoted yours.